# AndroidStudio auto skip debug line

Tags: android, android-studio

I use debuging in AndroidStudio, but sometime it skip some debug line.
Like the image below, when debug at line 49 then I press `Run to Cursor` [image], it should be point to line 50 but it not (it say The application is running)

I try to Clean Project, Invalidate Cache and Restart AndroidStudio but it still not work

How can I fix it? Any help or suggestion would be great aprreciated.

[image]

Comment: the  line which  you are debugging  is inside async task?]

Comment: @HourGlass no, moreover, even this line is in async task, it should point to next line and never display The application is running

Comment: I have seen such as Samsung launched on s4. Replaced the device and everything was fine.

Comment: @PeDuCKA I try to disconnect and reconnect to device but it still happened

Comment: @PhanVanLinh Tried to replace a device?

Comment: ok. is proguard enabled in debugging mode as well @PhanVanLinh which version of android studio you are using?

Answer (score 0):

If someone faces the same problem, and after Clean, Restart Android Studio, restart the device and it still not works.
Try restart the computer, it works with me